# How to fix timeout overflow warning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
targets.forEach((member, i) => { setTimeout(() => { member.roles.remove(role)) }, i*1000); });
```

I get the following in my console.

```
Timeout overflow warning: (7382828282...so on) does not fit into a 32 bit signed integer.
```

The roles get removed, but I get the above warning.

Comment: for what do you need such a big timeout?

Comment: Your array has more than 2.1 million members, and the delay for removing the last member is almost 25 days. Why should there be a delay in the first place?

Comment: It doesn't matter I think, I used something like that when I wanted to display some widgets in cascade on a dashboard. firstly loaded in 1 sec, second loaded in 2 sec, third loaded in 3 sec, etc...

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#maximum_delay_value) says: "_using delays larger than 2,147,483,647 ms [results] the timeout being executed immediately_".

Answer (score 1):

You could take an interval instead and use a counter/index for the data.

```
setInterval(
    (index => () => {
         // perform the action with your array       
         show(array[index]);
         index++;
    })(0),
    1000
);
```

Comment: How to I use your answer for performing this action of mine, with a one second delay.  targets.forEach(member => member.roles.remove(role)) I want to remove the roles at an interval of 1 second for each member.